# Listing the URLs of Maven dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project. I need to obtain the URLs of the resolved (transitive) dependencies for this project. What is the right way to do so?

Comment: What URLs are you referring to? Dependencies are hosted on the maven repository. Do you want to get the link to the repository page? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I want the URLs of the individual resolved dependencies.

Comment: Which URL? The URL of a dependencies does not say many things, cause it can come from a repository manager so this is in the End useless...Apart from that I don't understand what kind of problem you would like to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

To generate all dependencies you can use `mvn dependency:tree`, as it is described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

Generation of URLs requires to parse output of above command and convert it to address like this: `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit-dep/4.10/junit-dep-4.10-javadoc.jar`.

Comment: The output of `dependency:tree` is just a list of dependencies and you can't get a relationship between the dependencies and the URL where the dependency is coming from...And your example is only true if you consume the dependencies directly from Maven Central which is usually not the case...

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not store downloaded from URL, Only when you first time download location will available in logs, you can route the log to some file and search for "Downloaded:"